# Regex to match more than one word enclosed in double quotes.

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create an editor as the one in Stackoverflow. For that, I could not construct the regex to match the match more than one word enclosed with **. Looking for the pattern that can be used in Javascript/JQuery.

Can anybody please help me on this?

I used the code below,

```
var fulltext = this.getText();
var boldPattern= /\*\*(\w*)\*\*/g;
fulltext = fulltext.replace(boldPattern, "<b>$1</b>");
```

Comment: Just replace `var boldPattern= /\*\*(\w*)\*\*/g;` by `var boldPattern= /\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g;` and leave everything the same (which uses Explosion Pills' regex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\*\*.*?\*\*/
```

You need to escape the `*` so that it does not have its special regex meaning.  The `?` on the quantifier makes the match reluctant so it will only match up to the first `**`

Comment: it works only with single word not with more than one word enclosed with **